# How to convert an autocad file to a pdf file with clear view?

Tags: c#, aspose

I'm working on an asp.net project that converts autocad file .dwg to PDF.

I use the following code to do so :

```
using (var image = Aspose.CAD.Image.Load(filePath))
{
    // create an instance of CadRasterizationOptions & set resultant page size

    var rasterizationOptions = new Aspose.CAD.ImageOptions.CadRasterizationOptions()
    {
        PageSize = new Aspose.CAD.SizeF(image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height),
    };

    // save resultant PDF
    image.Save("****" + "***", new Aspose.CAD.ImageOptions.PdfOptions() { VectorRasterizationOptions = rasterizationOptions });
}
```

The pdf that i've got this:

[image]

another image

[image]
I want the building to be in the center of the pdf file and big enough to be useful for the user. How could i fix this view and make it clear?

Comment: I find that PDF to be of pretty high quality. Please read [ask] and be very specific in what you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the sample code shared by you. Can you please share that what issue you are having in exported PDF. Can you please share the source DWG file along with expected output PDF. Also, in your above image, the watermark on top left corner will be removed when you will set license of Aspose.CAD in your application.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, i cant share the dwg file for confidential reason. I want the building to be in the center of the pdf file and big enough to be useful for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to please try using following sample code on your end to set the print area for rendering file.

```
        var cadImage =(CadImage) Aspose.CAD.Image.Load("filePath");

        CadRasterizationOptions rasterizationOptions = new CadRasterizationOptions();
        rasterizationOptions.Layouts = new string[] { "Model" };
        rasterizationOptions.NoScaling = true;

        // note: preserving some empty borders around part of image is the responsibility of customer
        // top left point of region to draw
        Point topLeft = new Point(6156, 7053);
        double width = 3108;
        double height = 2489;

        CadVportTableObject newView = new CadVportTableObject();
        newView.Name = new CadStringParameter();
        newView.Name.Init("*Active");
        newView.CenterPoint.X = topLeft.X + width / 2f;
        newView.CenterPoint.Y = topLeft.Y - height / 2f;
        newView.ViewHeight.Value = height;
        newView.ViewAspectRatio.Value = width / height;

        for (int i = 0; i < cadImage.ViewPorts.Count; i++)
        {
            CadVportTableObject currentView = (CadVportTableObject)(cadImage.ViewPorts[i]);
            if (cadImage.ViewPorts.Count == 1 || string.Equals(currentView.Name.Value.ToLowerInvariant(), "*active"))
            {
                cadImage.ViewPorts[i] = newView;
                break;
            }
        }


        cadImage.Save("Saved.pdf", new Aspose.CAD.ImageOptions.PdfOptions() { VectorRasterizationOptions = rasterizationOptions });
```

Comment: I've tried your code. I got this error File Loading Failed: Input data is not recognized as valid pdf . when i openned the file i found it as chrome html document with blank page

Comment: I shall need the DWG file that is causing issue on your end to verify the issue. Unfortunately, without provision of requested information, I may not be able to help you further.